# PHP login from is not showing anything

Tags: php, forms, authentication

Nothing is showing on clicking submit button. Database connection and database field name is correct works well in registration page but not in this page.

Database connection is in connect.php which is included in php

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Login </title>
</head>

<body>
        <form action="login.php" METHOD="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <table border="1px" align="center">
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" align="center"> Login </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td> Email : </td>
                    <td> <input type=text name = email /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td> Password : </td>
                    <td> <input type=password name = password /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" align="right"> <input type=submit name=submit /> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </form>
</body>
```

PHP code in the same file

```
<? php

include("includes/connect.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $post_email = $_POST['email'];
        $post_password = $_POST['password'];


        if($post_email == '' or $post_password == '')
        {
            echo("Enter Something");
            exit();
        }

        else
        {
            $sql = " SELECT * FROM reg2 WHERE Email='$post_email' AND Password='$post_password' " ;
            $result = mysql_query($sql);


            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
                echo "Login Success";
            }

            else
            {
                echo "Login fail";
            }
        }

    mysql_close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: There is no PHP in what you are showing. The error might be in some code that you are not showing here, please try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **[PHP's built-in functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() **[compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)**. Make sure you **[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: What does "nothing is showing" mean? Does *anything* happen? If so, what? Does the PHP page attempt to load? Is it blank? What have you done to debug this? Have you checked the PHP error log? Also, **do not type in bold.**

Comment: `<? php`  Do you actually have a space there between the `?` and `php` ?

Comment: Unless this is for a class which does not allow the use a framework, I suggest that you look into using a PHP Framework, (my preference is [Laravel](https://laravel.com)) as they will help with handling logins and form processing in a much more secure way than rolling your own code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There are several small reasons why this code isn't working.   Several large reasons why this shouldn't be used for production.

First you stated the PHP is on the same page no need to reload the page if you are using echo to communicate results.  Remove action from your form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Second ad your quotes for your input types and names.

```
<input type="text" name = "email" />
<input type="password" name = "password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

Third to open a PHP block do this

```
<?php
```

not

```
<? php
```

Remove the space.

Note: I don't know how your db is set up or your db connect from your include file so this is what I see from the code you posted.

Now The reason you Shouldn't use this code for production.

Your data needs sanitation.

You need to use Mysqli or PDO instead of Mysql because Mysql is depreciated.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Use Prepared Statements.    http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Hash all passwords. I see no hashing in the above code.  look into password_hash() function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Hope this helps a little bit.